# PHP Ranking and updating all database rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, ranking

Trying to rank the rows in my table and then update a field in each row with its rank number. The ranking will be based on a field with a points value.

The database structure is as follows:

Table name: blogs

fields: ID, buildpointsNow, build_rank

I want to run a cron job that will rank each row depending on its buildpointsNow value and then update its build_rank with that rank number.

So far i have tried:

```
UPDATE   blogs
JOIN     (SELECT    p.id,
@curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
FROM      blogs p
JOIN      (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
ORDER BY  p.buildpointsNow DESC
) ranks ON (ranks.id = blogs.id)
SET      blogs.build_rank = blogs.build_rank;
```

And also:

```
update blogs cross join
   (select @rn := 0) vars
set build_rank = (@rn := @rn + 1);
order by buildpointsNow;
```

Both of these throw no errors and do update the database rows. However they do not order the builds rank depending on the buildpointsNow field. They instead update each row in its order of creation / its ID.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`blogs` need to be ordered by `buildpointsNow` before adding `@curRank`:

```
update blogs
join (
  select p.id, @curRank := @curRank + 1 as rank
  from (select id from blogs order by buildpointsNow) p
  join (select @curRank := 0) r) ranks on ranks.id = blogs.id
set blogs.build_rank = ranks.rank;
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce425/1)

Comment: Just checked, at that actually doesn't update the table. I was incorrect in my question, the first example doesn't update the table neither. Anyway to modify the second example so that it works correctly? The second example DOES update but as the question, just not ordered by the points field.

Comment: @user2921557, sorry there was typo in my earlier solution. changed `blogs.build_rank = blogs.build_rank` to `blogs.build_rank = ranks.rank`

Comment: Excellent, that does update the table. But the ordering seems to be odd. For example, the blog with the rank of '1' has 10 points, yet the  build with 4 points is 17th and the build with 303 is 14th. Any ideas on that one?

Comment: @user2921557, Sorry I can't tell the problem with your explanation. Can you add some sample data? It's possible buildpointsNow should be in descending order?

Comment: I thought that but no. Ill do the sample data as ID(points,rank). 1(142,6), 2(183,10), 5(101,2), 10(160,7), 15(75,22), 20(15,19), 25(18,9)

Comment: @user2921557, here's a [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce425/1), it shows that after the update, records with lower points having lower rank.

Comment: My fault on this one. Database structure error. I made this table a while back when i was learning and the points field was set up as a varchar. So the ordering was being done as 1, 12, 14, 130, 20, 2000, 4, 45, 8, 890 etc. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

**Create a separate table and store ranking order there.** You need a column with `post_id` and one with `score`. Every time you add/subtract `points` from `score` modify that column. And when you need to display the posts in ranking order, just sort that second lighter table table and join the posts heavier table.

Also make sure you index the `score` column.